# What is the meaning of -> List[int] in this function declaration?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to understand the declaration of this function: `->List[int]:`

I have learned the basics of Python and I never saw function declaration like this before

```py
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#id32

Comment: we can use this - from typing import List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a new feature in version 3.5. You can see the docs.
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html

Answer (score 30):

It is a so called "type hint" (or "function annotation"; these are available since Python [3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)).

- `-> List[int]` means that the function should return a list of integers.
- `nums: List[int], target: int` means that `nums` is expected to be a list of integers and that `target` is expected to be an integer.

This is not a hard requirement, though, i.e. you can still call the function with objects of different types passed for these parameters and the function can as well return something different than a list of intergers (unlike in other languages like Java where providing wrong types would result in a compile error). To put it differently: Type hints are irrelevant for the program execution, they are ignored at runtime (ignoring the type hints is just the default behavior, but they are available at runtime via `__annotations__`, so you *could* do something with them).

Type hints can express the intent of the author and can be checked before program execution by tools like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) (these can check e.g. that a function is only called with parameters of the correct type and returns something of the correct type).

Note that `List` is not available in the standard namespace (unlike `list`), but (at least before Python 3.9) instead needs to be imported from [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) which also

- provides other types for standard types, like `Set`, `Dict`, `Tuple`, `Callable` etc.
- allows to define own types
- provides typed versions of other types, like [`NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead of [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

From Python 3.9 on, one could as well use the standard `list` constructor for the type hint, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections).

Comment: I am a newbie and this is an in-depth explanation .thanks man I appreciate it